# Why I can't set a breakpoint in some of the Java source file (readonly source of plugin jar) in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I'm tracing into eclipse LTK plugin. I could set a breakpoint in some of the readonly java source for LTK. (for example ProcessorBasedRefactoring.java)

[image]

However, I couldn't set a breakpoint in some source files. (for example JavaRenameProcessor).

[image]

When I tried to set a method breakpoint, I got "Cannot create method breakpoint, method signature not available." error message.

What might be wrong? Why I can't set a breakpoint in some of the (binary) Java source file?
[image]

### ADDED:

For a simple workaround to this issue, I just set a breakpoint wherever possible, and then open the java source to click a line. Then, I can use command-R so that eclipse executes up to the line that I point to.

### ADDED2:

The breakpoint was there, but eclipse doesn't show it.

[image]

The other thing that I noticed was that the java file, just disappears from the IDE when I restart the debugger. And even when I reopen it in eclipse.
[image]

I got this error message - "zip file closed".
[image]

And then I can see the source code only when I trace into the method that the java source contains.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the class is compiled without debug information and/or the byte code is obfuscated.

Comment: I found the break point was just not shown and  jar file has "zip file closed" error. I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem today, but figured it out.
I was debugging my project like I normally do, as a Remote Java Application. In the Debug Configuration's Source Lookup Path, I had added the folder containing the source code of a JAR referenced by my project - this lets Eclipse know where to find the source code when debugging classes in the JAR.

In the Eclipse Project Explorer under "Referenced Libraries", I expanded the JAR to the class I wanted to debug and double-clicked it. This opens a source window for the class. Note that this window's tab shows the file with extension ".class" and a "010" file icon.  You can set breakpoints in this window.

When one of the breakpoints is hit, Eclipse opens another source window for the same class! Both windows show the same source code content but they have different functionality.  This window's tab shows the file with extension ".java" and a hollow "J" file icon. Per the [Eclipse Help](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm), this file icon indicates "Java file which is not on a build path". This is the window where you can step through the code. But setting a breakpoint in this window does not work. When I try to set a breakpoint here, no error is shown but the breakpoint simply isn't added.  I have to instead set the breakpoints in the ".class" window.

In the screenshots that were posted for this question, one can see the different file icons. The file selected in the first screenshot has a "010" file icon indicating it is the class file. The file selected in the 2nd screenshot has the hollow "J" file icon.

Another way to distinguish the two windows is when you hover the mouse over the tabs - the .class file window shows the class name without an extension, and the other window shows the file name with the full path and ".java" extension.

Answer (score -1):

1. Download java source code from open source website, the file's form is `XXX.zip`, not `XXX.jar`.
2. Build path -->c onfigure build path, enter the page, choose libraries, and open a jar file, find "Source attachment", and choose it, you can find a button is named "Edit" on the right, click it, and type the `xxx.zip` what you downloaded path into it.
3. back to your debug page, continue your work

Good luck! I hope my answer can help you.